# Execute Python file every few seconds without time loop

Tags: python, loops, timer, spotipy

I'm still a beginner and wrote some code to pull the currently playing track from the Spotify API. This works fine when I execute it once, but I want it to constantly update. I found a solution to execute a function every n seconds but this only prints the track that I first played. Even after the changing the song it still prints the song I played before.

The code I tried:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import cred
import time


scope = "user-read-playback-state"

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=cred.client_id, client_secret=cred.client_secret, redirect_uri=cred.redirect_url, scope=scope, open_browser=False))

results = sp.current_user_playing_track()
starttime = time.time()

while True:
    print (results["item"]["name"])
    print (results["item"]["artists"][0]["name"])
    time.sleep(5.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 5.0))
```

Comment: You need to put `results = sp.current_user_playing_track()` inside the loop. Right now you call it just once, before the loop.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that `results` is not updated inside the `while` loop.

So simply move the `while True:` statement above `results = sp.current_user_playing_track()` so that the info is actually udpated each loop.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to only execute again when the song changes? I guess that would be a bit more complicated.